# some questions about DEFINE use method in NCVERILOG

Tags: logic, c-preprocessor, verilog

I have try use define to simplify the writing and all the parameters are really written

```
//...
parameter  BLEZ = 1001011;
parameter  BLTZ = 1001100;
parameter  SRA  = 1001101;

`define R_type1 ((op == MOVA)||(op == MOVB)||(op == ADD)||(op == SUB)||(op == AND)||(op == OR)||(op == XOR)||(op == NOT)||(op == SLT))
`define R_type2 ((op == LSL)||(op == LSR)||(op == SRA))
`define JR_type ((op == JMR))
`define J_type  ((op == JMP))
`define I_type  ((op == ADI)||(op == SBI)||(op == ANI)||(op == ORI)||(op == XRI)||(op == AIU)||(op == SIU)(op == JML))
`define LW  ((op == LD))
`define SW  ((op == ST))
`define Branch  ((op == BZ)||(op == BNZ)||(op == BGEZ)||(op == BGTZ)||(op == BLEZ)||(op == BLTZ))

always@(op)
begin
RegWrite_id    = ((`LW)||(`R_type1)||(`R_type2)||(`I_type));
RegDst_id      = ((`LW)||(`R_type1)||(`R_type2)||(`I_type));
MemWrite_id    = 1;//(`SW);
MemRead_id     = (`LW);
MemToReg_id    = (`LW);
ALUSrcA_id     = (`R_type2);
ALUSrcB_id     = (`I_type);
PCSource       = {`JR_type,`J_type,Z};
end
```

I think there are nothing wrong in logic level but it always gave some ERROR
like this:

```
RegWrite_id    = ((`LW)||(`R_type1)||(`R_type2)||(`I_type));
                                                        |
ncvlog: *E,EXPRPA (Decode_Unit.v,71|56): expecting a right parenthesis (')') [4.3][9.7(IEEE)].
(`define macro: I_type [Decode_Unit.v line 64], file: Decode_Unit.v line 71)
RegWrite_id    = ((`LW)||(`R_type1)||(`R_type2)||(`I_type));
                                                          |
ncvlog: *E,EXPSMC (Decode_Unit.v,71|58): expecting a semicolon (';') [9.2.2(IEEE)].
RegWrite_id    = ((`LW)||(`R_type1)||(`R_type2)||(`I_type));
                                                          |
ncvlog: *E,NOTSTT (Decode_Unit.v,71|58): expecting a statement [9(IEEE)].
RegDst_id      = ((`LW)||(`R_type1)||(`R_type2)||(`I_type));
               |
ncvlog: *E,EXPLPA (Decode_Unit.v,72|15): expecting a left parenthesis ('(') [12.1.2][7.1(IEEE)].
RegDst_id      = ((`LW)||(`R_type1)||(`R_type2)||(`I_type));
                                                        |
ncvlog: *E,EXPRPA (Decode_Unit.v,72|56): expecting a right parenthesis (')') [4.3][9.7(IEEE)].
(`define macro: I_type [Decode_Unit.v line 64], file: Decode_Unit.v line 72)
RegDst_id      = ((`LW)||(`R_type1)||(`R_type2)||(`I_type));
                                                          |
ncvlog: *E,EXPSMC (Decode_Unit.v,72|58): expecting a semicolon (';') [12.1.2][7.1(IEEE)].
MemWrite_id    = 1;//(`SW);
               |
ncvlog: *E,EXPLPA (Decode_Unit.v,73|15): expecting a left parenthesis ('(') [12.1.2][7.1(IEEE)].
MemRead_id     = (`LW);
```

and all the parameters are really  written

it's confusing....
please give me some coaching

Answer (score 1):

You forgot an `||` operator between the last two terms in the `I_type` macro.

Also note that if you want your parameters to be interpreted as binary number, you will have to add `'b` in front of them, example `'b1010` is the number ten in binary while `1010` is one thousand and ten.

Answer (score 0):

As Unn already pointed out, `I_type` is missing an `||` and and the radix needs to be specified (otherwise it is assumed decimal).

> example `'b1010` is the number ten in binary while `1010` is one thousand and ten.

Additionally, `` `define `` are a painful to debug as you experienced. Be aware that `` `define `` are applied to the global space based on compiling order. This means another module could use the same macro without defining it if it was compiled latter, which can lead to confusion and bugs is not done correctly. It is recommended to avoid (or at least minimize) the use of `` `define `` in RTL.

With your code I will suggest changing your `` `define `` to `wire`. It will synthesize to the same but is much easier to debug. I intellectually left the `||` bug in to demonstrate.

```
wire R_type1 = ((op == MOVA)||(op == MOVB)||(op == ADD)||(op == SUB)||(op == AND)||(op == OR)||(op == XOR)||(op == NOT)||(op == SLT));
wire R_type2 = ((op == LSL)||(op == LSR)||(op == SRA));
wire JR_type = ((op == JMR));
wire J_type  = ((op == JMP));
wire I_type  = ((op == ADI)||(op == SBI)||(op == ANI)||(op == ORI)||(op == XRI)||(op == AIU)||(op == SIU)(op == JML));
wire LW      = ((op == LD));
wire SW      = ((op == ST));
wire Branch  = ((op == BZ)||(op == BNZ)||(op == BGEZ)||(op == BGTZ)||(op == BLEZ)||(op == BLTZ));

always@* // IMPORTANT :: use '*', not 'op'
begin
  RegWrite_id    = ((LW)||(R_type1)||(R_type2)||(I_type));
  RegDst_id      = ((LW)||(R_type1)||(R_type2)||(I_type));
  MemWrite_id    = 1;//(SW);
  MemRead_id     = (LW);
  MemToReg_id    = (LW);
  ALUSrcA_id     = (R_type2);
  ALUSrcB_id     = (I_type);
  PCSource       = {JR_type,J_type,Z};
end
```

Combinational always blocks should use auto-sensitivity; `always@*` or the synonymous `always@(*)`. Auto-sensitivity been supported since IEEE1364-2001. Specifying the sensitivity list is only recommended you are following strict IEEE1364-1995, or for a excluding signals in behavior module that will not be synthesized.